# 2 jDateChooser how to disable the date of other jDatechooser

Tags: java, jdatechooser

I have 2 jdatechooser, 1 is for check in and 1 is for checkout.
How can I disable the date of my jdatechooser checkout if my jdatechooser check in is selected the date today and the checkout will disable the date yesterday or I set the checkin date Oct-20-2016 the checkout will disable the date from Oct-20-2016 Oct-19-2016 Oct-18-2016 like that...

```
jDateChooser2.setValue(jDateChooser1.getValue().plusDays(1));
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8zxj.png

Comment: Please post an [MCVE] showing what you are trying to do.

Comment: jDateChooser2.setValue(jDateChooser1.getValue().plusDays(1));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**After** a date has been selected in dateChooser1 , if `Date date` is the minimum allowed date, use:

```
jDateChooser2.getJCalendar().setMinSelectableDate(date);
```

Comment: i did that already but i want to add 1 day for my checkout. i dont want to check in and check out with the same date.

Comment: i use this 1 jDateChooser1.getJCalendar().setMinSelectableDate(new Date()); but i want my jdatechooser 2 disable the past date before the date picked in jdatechooser1